# Two network interfaces on different networks but only one can access the internet

Tags: networking

I have two network cards:
*enp4s0* has a public static ip (I have edited the ip below).
*enp2s0* has a local static ip (behind my router, 192.168.0.1).

All requests should by default go through *enp4s0* and all requests coming from *enp2s0* should be returned to *enp2s0*.

*enp4s0* has no problems sending or receiving requests.
*enp2s0* on the other hand cannot send requests but receiving SSH connections and pings still works.

```
$ ping -I enp2s0 8.8.8.8
$ ping -I enp2s0 127.0.0.1
```

Results in timeout and

```
$ ping -I enp2s0 localhost
connect: Network is unreachable
```

However pinging the router or any other local device works.

```
$ ping -I enp2s0 192.168.0.1
$ ping -I enp2s0 192.168.0.3
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255

post-up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.0.2 table routetable
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 table routetable
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.0.2/32 table routetable
post-up ip rule add to 192.168.0.2/32 table routetable
```

**$ /sbin/route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.11.136.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp4s0
10.11.136.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
```

**$ ip route**

```
default via 10.11.136.1 dev enp4s0
10.11.136.0/22 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.11.136.13
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2
```

**/etc/iproute2/rt_tables**

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1 routetable
```

**$ ifconfig**

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::222:15ff:fe3c:5d29  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:22:15:3c:5d:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 344  bytes 52868 (52.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 292  bytes 43536 (43.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 2  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.11.136.13  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.11.139.255
    inet6 fe20::2ade:d0ff:fe01:4e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 93:de:d0:03:02:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2609  bytes 450767 (450.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2949  bytes 494772 (494.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 848  bytes 68061 (68.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 848  bytes 68061 (68.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

**$ sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0**

```
ifdown: interface enp2s0 not configured

Configuring interface enp2s0=enp2s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255        dev     enp2s0 label enp2s0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up enp2s0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the enp2s0 stanza read:

```
# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. I get this error: ifdown: interface enp2s0 not configured. I have updated the question.

Comment: Is there any change if you reboot?

Comment: No that did not change anything

Comment: Any clues in: `dmesg | grep enp`?

Comment: Not really. But I think it is the default gateway that is the problem. The default gateway is now on enp4s0 so that works but if I change that to enp2s0 then that work and enp4s0 does not. So there seems to problems with dual gateways?

Comment: If enp4s0 has a public static IP, how can it be in the 192.168.0.1 network? How can it be public if it is behind the router? Also, I am suspicious that the 192.168.0.2 address is actually in the DHCP pool in the router. How is enp4s0 static when your file says dhcp?

Comment: enp4s0 is not in the 192.168.0.1 network or behind a router, how did you get that? It's technically static from my isp (bound to the MAC) but they have accidentally disabled it a few times so when reactivated the ip has changed. So I keep it on dhcp so that if it ever change, I don't have do anything. 192.168.0.2 is in the dhcp pool.

Comment: It is not safe to specify a static IP that is inside the DHCP pool.

Comment: Of course not but this is my own route so I control which device get which IP and 192.168.0.2 will always get that IP even on auto.